# How to show arguments of java function in vim + eclim?

Tags: java, eclipse, vim, eclim

I have configured vim + eclim OK. Now I can use Ctrl+X and Ctrl+U complete functions. But there is no arguments hint. For example,

```
FileInputStream fins = new FileInputStream(/* what arguments can be used here? eclipse will show those but eclim not */);
```

how to show arguments hint in vim + eclim?

Comment: Did you try `new FileInputStream` <- here, and `new FileInputStream(` <- here?

Answer (score 0):

*Resurrecting this old question, since I stumbled on this.*

You can use eclim to lookup the java docs of the class and look through the list of constructors that way using the [`:JavaDocSearch`](http://eclim.org/vim/java/javadoc.html#searching) command.

Because the command uses a browser to render the javadocs, you'll need to add to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:EclimBrowser = 'browser-executable-name'
```

Replacing `browser-executable-name` with your console-based browser of choice. Example: `lynx`, `links`, `w3m`

Then navigate over `FileInputStream` with your cursor and run the command `:JavaDocSearch` and it will pop up the java doc for the class.

Or enter the class name manually: `:JavaDocSearch java.io.FileInputStream`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the YouCompleteMe (YCM) plugin with options

```
let g:ycm_add_preview_to_completeopt = 1
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion = 1
```

Note that this does not work for your Constructor invocations. But at least prototypes for method calls will be shown.

Also, if you don't like the auto-popup of YCM, it can be switched off.